# cordova-file-plugin cannot able to delete image from extended sdcard

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to delete images on extended sdcard, I can delete images on device storage but I am not able to delete images on extended sdcard.

Here is my code:

```
var url = "file:///storage/0403-0201/Instamotion/vx_2/closed/W0LPD9EC5G1117912_image_1.jpg";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(url, function(file) {

console.log(file)

file.remove(function() {

  console.log(url + " deleted");

}, function(error) {

  console.log(error);

});

}, function(error) {

  console.log(error)

});
```